# Set theMessage's content to have multiple lines in applescript

Tags: applescript, automator

In an automator service, I have a bash script that passes two variables to an applescript that then inputs those into an email. I want both variables to be on a different lines within the email.

```
on run {input, parameters}
set macPath to item 1 of input
set windowsPath to item 2 of input
set messageContent to macPath & return & linefeed & return & windowsPath

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    activate
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {content:messageContent}
    open theMessage
end tell
end run
```

I've tried return, linefeed and escape characters but none seem to work and the contents of my message always end up on one line. Is there any way to do this in applescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realised that the *content* property supports "rich text" so linebreaks can be introduced with the `<br>` tag such as:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    activate
    set sendToAddress to ""
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {content:"Line 1 <br> line 2"}
    open theMessage
end tell
```